# Why my PySimpleGUI crash on Mac OS X 10.15.1, but works fine on Mac OS X 10.13

Tags: python, macos, crash, pysimplegui

Crash logs:

```
Process:               Test6 [1858]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/*/App-1.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Test6
Identifier:            App-1.1
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Test6 [1858]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-23 18:29:43.866 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y906)
Anonymous UUID:        9952FE86-6763-6994-E7F6-20DEB896E05E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E4ED98DC-0E7E-4921-BCA0-511DE41E4C5D

Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld2 mode
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7064249a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff706ff6cb pthread_kill + 384
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff705caa1c abort + 120
3   Python                          0x000000010ac1b1ae fatal_error + 547
4   Python                          0x000000010ac1a7de Py_InitializeEx + 136
5   App-1.1                         0x000000010ab47768 main + 440
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff704f32e5 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000114b46dc0  rcx: 0x00007ffee50b9518  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000307  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee50b9540  rsp: 0x00007ffee50b9518
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000054f023e4  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000307  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff7064249a  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000010aea5020

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10ab46000 -        0x10ab47fff +App-1.1 (0) <F8D9BE9C-E118-36FB-A55B-5FE23569915D> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/App-1.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Test6
       0x10ab4c000 -        0x10acd3fff +Python (0) <836E2A2F-2279-3E85-B279-61047DAB23C5> /Users/USER/Desktop/*/App-1.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x114a7d000 -        0x114b0db5f  dyld (733.6) <DAFEA246-2F9A-3DCB-A37C-4246D4F92770> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff2d695000 -     0x7fff2d6a4ff7  libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib (76) <D25428B0-07E7-33DA-8939-5ED3C50D3154> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
    0x7fff38fdf000 -     0x7fff3945efe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1673.126) <15D61616-B29B-3BDB-8624-4B84A4956485> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff6ce76000 -     0x7fff6ce78fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (112) <83F42398-DB41-3BB2-B8A1-10D78C4B5778> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff6d33e000 -     0x7fff6d33fff3  libSystem.B.dylib (1281) <1DD1BCD2-2C85-3B81-8CAF-224FB042F441> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff6d61c000 -     0x7fff6d66ffff  libc++.1.dylib (800.7) <1D42387D-206A-3F06-9B5F-705B83EAC295> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff6d670000 -     0x7fff6d684fff  libc++abi.dylib (800.7) <D89ABFBF-3754-35AB-BAEE-FBF14857F79B> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff6e0e5000 -     0x7fff6e0e7ff7  libfakelink.dylib (149) <528A0ABE-B583-3DA1-8E5B-9CA7E89303DE> /usr/lib/libfakelink.dylib
    0x7fff6e1f7000 -     0x7fff6e44fff7  libicucore.A.dylib (64243.0.1) <4CBF52D7-7235-34C8-9FF1-8657076B604F> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff6f17e000 -     0x7fff6f1afff6  libobjc.A.dylib (781) <D866A31E-5CB1-3327-8D22-C4F83C9225D0> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff6f856000 -     0x7fff6f868fff  libz.1.dylib (76) <3EC7A143-AF2D-35EE-9C08-542B2907E3D2> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff702ce000 -     0x7fff702d3ff7  libcache.dylib (83) <74F6459D-3606-3ADB-9808-F6B0FE70062D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff702d4000 -     0x7fff702dfff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60165) <1333752F-5117-3E86-803A-06E166D80C8C> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff702e0000 -     0x7fff702e7fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (101.2) <0437EBEF-8191-3912-A365-D6BB75C7A810> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff702e8000 -     0x7fff702f1fff  libcopyfile.dylib (166.40.1) <7FAF372E-BAD5-30E6-A8F2-A3D06B91DC80> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff702f2000 -     0x7fff70389fef  libcorecrypto.dylib (866.40.8) <AE25C9EE-5D63-3E49-B3AA-D482D35C085A> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff704a0000 -     0x7fff704e1ff0  libdispatch.dylib (1173.40.5) <1FF421B6-4BF0-3B5F-8F56-5ED3B3EFE06F> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff704e2000 -     0x7fff70517fff  libdyld.dylib (733.6) <2FA4B359-624B-337C-9207-CDCF841C2E52> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff70518000 -     0x7fff70518ffb  libkeymgr.dylib (30) <7EEF9246-30B4-34DD-8AD6-79679D1A7784> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff70526000 -     0x7fff70526ff7  liblaunch.dylib (1738.40.10) <CC02D5B3-A95D-3B16-8EE5-D62521CFE899> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff70527000 -     0x7fff7052cff7  libmacho.dylib (949.0.1) <6C3E49B2-594D-3B9D-82DB-C4ABEB9788AB> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff7052d000 -     0x7fff7052fff3  libquarantine.dylib (110.40.3) <A1BCAA32-A194-3DBE-9930-8F49A4AEF284> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff70530000 -     0x7fff70531ff7  libremovefile.dylib (48) <DD7AE862-F179-3C07-A4FC-5775DDD4D3E6> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff70532000 -     0x7fff70549fff  libsystem_asl.dylib (377.40.1) <ECE44856-D279-3B5D-A0AA-8BE421D200C4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff7054a000 -     0x7fff7054afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (74) <DC521115-905A-3A0D-9337-C55FACCEA85F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff7054b000 -     0x7fff705d2ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (1353.41.1) <5AD50779-955E-3F56-BCB9-1E14833B3455> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff705d3000 -     0x7fff705d6fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (1061.40.2) <7A2329E0-3C84-3DB7-BC32-E7796C50D621> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff705d7000 -     0x7fff705daff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (114) <DF341577-A307-3722-BB24-D4AACEAB19B3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff705db000 -     0x7fff705e2fff  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1353.41.1) <E862B5B1-A367-39CA-8319-B2F9DFADF606> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
    0x7fff705e3000 -     0x7fff705eaffb  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (1096.40.7) <2A9C6F3E-427B-332E-BDD3-D4651306F3DE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff705eb000 -     0x7fff705ecffb  libsystem_featureflags.dylib (17) <B94C0052-B75A-3169-80AA-5F480588AF6E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
    0x7fff705ed000 -     0x7fff7063aff7  libsystem_info.dylib (538) <18CC56C5-5325-3375-BF99-FAE7F4F19DDD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff7063b000 -     0x7fff70667ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (6153.41.3) <18918E9C-45BC-3D5A-A6B6-3DBC60EEE2E1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff70668000 -     0x7fff706afff7  libsystem_m.dylib (3178) <636A1A1C-7AFC-3E82-B86B-0173912A3437> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff706b0000 -     0x7fff706d7ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (283.40.1) <F82A587B-44A2-3699-A218-9D3ECEE23D5A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff706d8000 -     0x7fff706e5ff3  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (1095.40.22) <7F206A43-A941-3BAB-AE3A-16169F2FE6AB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff706e6000 -     0x7fff706effff  libsystem_notify.dylib (241) <C95CC58E-35E7-3828-AA2A-6EED73C12DE5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff706f0000 -     0x7fff706f9fe7  libsystem_platform.dylib (220) <0CCDD81F-0891-3400-8A97-6CAC3BBBE2F9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff706fa000 -     0x7fff70704ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (416.40.3) <53C65598-9E9E-36FF-BDC2-74F228E58C5C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff70705000 -     0x7fff70709ffb  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (1217.41.1) <2183D15E-2CFD-3160-80CE-A948F0529005> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff7070a000 -     0x7fff7070cfff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (62.40.2) <D2782294-ACDC-30FF-A794-B4C1B324526B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
    0x7fff7070d000 -     0x7fff70714ffb  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (1238.40.4) <A44E4405-E22E-32E9-83DE-8C7A82401DA0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff70715000 -     0x7fff7072bff2  libsystem_trace.dylib (1147.40.13) <376CC435-E656-37D9-A5FF-C49B6E4525E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff7072d000 -     0x7fff70732ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <44448F1F-08E5-3425-ADBA-C38A9E8F90C7> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff70733000 -     0x7fff70767ff6  libxpc.dylib (1738.40.10) <99CC9436-D653-3762-ADBB-9054EBD1BA2B> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 16785
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=366.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=366.5M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=557.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=557.6M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           164.3M       19 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                       1024K        4 
__DATA                            2581K       49 
__DATA_CONST                        20K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       353.3M        4 
__OBJC_RO                         32.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1780K        2 
__TEXT                            13.2M       47 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.0G      138 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   632.6M      138 

Model: MacBookPro14,2, BootROM 202.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 3.1 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.44f2
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisGraphics650Item, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x171), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.106.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1435.3)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.1f1, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple T1 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.3
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.3
```

Comment: Can you post the Python error messages so that the crash can be analysed to see  if PySimpleGUI has a difference?  Does the test harness run ok?  Just add a call to sg.main() to test that.  It displays all of the Elements in a test window.

Comment: Is Python error not included in my crash log? Please kindly tell me how to retrieve Python log in Mac OS 10, thx.

Comment: The Python error would be printed out in your "console" window where your normal "prints" would be output.

Comment: @thecr0w did you figure this one out?

Comment: @the_ccalderon, not yet.